# Is it valid to factor polynomials applied to operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L} (V)$ and $T^{2} = I$ and $-1$ is not an
> eigenvalue of $T$. Prove that $T = I$.

From the equality, we have
$$T^{2} - I = 0$$

This implies that
$$T^{2} - I^2 = 0$$

Then I "factored" the LHS to obtain
$$(T + I) (T - I) = 0$$

Since $-1$ is not an eigenvalue, this implies $T = I$.
Is it valid to factor the polynomial on the left as if it were a regular polynomial? Or should I try a different approach to this problem?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: You can always look at it this way: The fact that $(T+I)(T-I)=T^2-I$ as maps implies that $0=(T+I)^{-1}0=(T+I)^{-1}(T^2-I)=T-I$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Would you mind clarifying the reason for each equality? Sorry, it isn't quite clear to me what you did at each step. Additionally, the first step seems to have implied that (T+I) is invertible. The question does not assume $T$ finite-dimensional, so we do not know if $T+I$ is invertible.

Comment: So our only assumption is that $-1$ is not in the point-spectrum of $T$?

Comment: Well, in that case, let $x\in V$. Then, $0=(T^2-I)x=(T+I)(T-I)x$, so that $(T-I)x\in \textrm{ker}(T+I)$. This implies that $(T-I)x=0$, since $(T+I)$ is injective.

Comment: Basically, you just need a reason why $AB=0$ implies $B=0$. As proved above, it suffices that $A$ is injective. Similarly, if $B$ is surjective, then $A$ would have to be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also look at it this way: you got that the polynomial $(x-1)(x+1)$ annihilates $T$ so the minimal polynomial $m_T(x)$ must divide it. Since $-1$ is not an eigenvalue, it is not a root of $m_T$ so it has to be $m_T(x)=x-1$. Therefore $$0=m_T(T)=T-I \implies T=I.$$